# Create View in Oracle from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, view, pivot

I got  completely lost when creating a view in Oracle from multiple tables.

#### That's what I have:

Table 1:
PKEY, Name, Street

Table 2:
PKEY, REFPKEY, MUID, MUVAL

These table are filled as follows:
Table 1

```
1, Hans, 118th West
2, Dick, 1st Av.
3, etc ...
```

Table 2

```
1-1, 1, TEL, +1 56984
1-2, 1, EMA, hans@outlook.com
2-1, 2, TEL, +49 7564862
2-2, 2, EMA, dick@cheynie.com
2-3, 2, MBT, +112911
3-1, etc ...
```

#### What I want as a view:

```
PKEY, NAME, Street,     Phone,        Email,            Mobile
1,    Hans, 118th West, +1 56984,    hans@outlook.com
2,    Dick, 1st Av.,    +49 7564862, dick@cheynie.com,  +112911
3, etc...
```

So  PKEY, Name, Street can be easily extracted from table_1 with

```
     Create view example_view AS 
     SELECT PKEY, Name, Street FROM table_1
```

However, how can the remaining columns of the view be defined? How can I sort the data of table_2 into the view, i.e. assigning the data by matching table_1.pkey with table_2.refpkey and what is marked "EMA" in table 2 should be filled into the column Email, what is marked "TEL" in table 2 should be filled  intothe column Phone, and so on.

I guess it needs juggling with UNION and JOIN, but I did not manage it for hours.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select t1.pkey, t1.name, t1.street,
       Max(case when t2.muid = 'TEL' then t2.muval end) as phone,
       Max(case when t2.muid = 'EMA' then t2.muval end) as email,
       Max(case when t2.muid = 'MBT' then t2.muval end) as mobile
  From table1 t1
  Left join table2 t2 on t1.pkey = t2.refpkey
Group by t1.pkey, t1.name, t1.street;
```